# Change comment and block comment colors separately in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find out how to specify one color for single-line comment and another for block comment (multi-line).

The below works for setting ALL comments to a certain color:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments" :"#ff0022",
    }
```

Is there a way to specify them individually? e.g. `"blockComment" : "#00FF00", "commentLine" : "#FF00222"`

Comment: if your language server sets different TextMate scopes to these comments you can set different colors

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks. Tried the `"textMateRules"`, the colors for the two types of comments can now be customised.

Comment: post the edits as answer to the question so it can be marked as resolved

Comment: @rioV8 done. Aside, I do wonder why `'punctuation.definition.comment'` didn't seem to come out right.

Comment: looking at theme files: using an array as scopes is an `OR` of scopes, I think if you want `AND` of scopes you have to use a string like `"scope1 scope2"`

Comment: @rioV8 String `"comment.line, punctuation.definition.comment.js"` works. Really helpful of you. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"textMateRules"` to set scope settings for `"comment.block"` and `"comment.line"` can set the colors individually.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "comment.block",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#0000"
        }
    },
    {
        "scope": "comment.line",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#0000FF"
        }
    }],
}
```

[image: Javascript]

To change punctuations `"punctuation.definition.comment.js"` (js):

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "comment.line, punctuation.definition.comment.js",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#00FF00"
        }
    }]
}
```

[image]